# Listing DataTable values

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datatable

I have a DataTable (`id`) that has one column (`LinkID`). The items in the rows for this column are numbers. I am trying to list these numbers in the following format:

```
1, 2, 30, 494, etc...
```

How would I get all of the numbers and list them in that way?

Here is what I have tried:

```
foreach (DataRow row in id.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in id.Columns)
    {
        var test = row[0].ToString();
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        ls.Add(test);
        MessageBox.Show(ls.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can the following:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in id.Rows)
{
   test.Add(row[0].ToString());
}

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", test.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you know you only have *one* column in the table, I recommend looping and using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to build up your string, like so:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

// Cycle through the rows, append the field.
var query = 
    from row in id.AsEnumerable()
    select builder.Append(row.Field<int>(0)).Append(", ");

// Get the last or default, if there are no rows, builder will be null.
builder = query.LastOrDefault();

// If the builder is null, there are no rows, return
// null.
if (builder == null) return null;

// The builder is not null, there is content
// in the StringBuilder.
// This removes the last ", " which is appended at the end if
// there are any elements.
if (builder != null) builder.Length -= 2;

// Return the string from the builder.
return builder.ToString();
```

Since the [`StringBuilder.Append` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wt5x6h.aspx) uses a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), you can have the LINQ query return the same instance, and just get the last one while you keep appending the comma-separated values.

You use the [`LastOrDefault` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301849.aspx) so that if there are no rows, you get a `null` value, indicating you had no rows.

You get two benefits here; for a large number of rows, you don't build up a list of strings that you have to concatenate later.  Instead, you're building the string and increasing the capacity *as you need it* with the `StringBuilder` (which pre-allocates capacity).

Also, without having to call [`Array.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) (or some other string concatenation methods) at the end, you end up sparing extra concatenation operations *again*.